# How to schedule events with msql

Tags: mysql, events

I'm trying to make an event that will execute every 1 hour.

Here is the code.

```
mysql> DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `clean`;

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `clean`
       ON SCHEDULE
         EVERY 1 HOUR
         STARTS '2017-07-07 16:00.00'
         DO
           SET @isTime = IF(table_name.programed_time = NOW(), 'y', 'n');
           IF @isTime = 'y' THEN DELETE FROM `cell_name`
             WHERE `cell_name` = 'value'
```

I want the event to run only on Mondays at 16:00. So in my app I have the code to save the date of each 1st Monday of each month at 16:00 in a table.

But I'm having this error when I run this query.

```
Unknown type of declaration near to IF.
Something is wrong in its syntax near 'IF @isTime ='y' 
THEN DELETE FROM `cell_name` WHERE `cell_name 'in the line
```

Someone could tell me what I doing wrong.

Comment: You need to read about triggers in mysql

Comment: No such thing in MySQL.

Comment: @SloanThrasher No such thing as what? MySQL has had triggers and events for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling of events in mysql involves you understanding how triggers work. Just check out this detailed tutorial and I believe it would go a long way. https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

> Alternatively

Based on your question I really believe that cronjob will be best suited for your need. Check out this article. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 1):

Since your event has more than one statement, your issue is probably that you need to convert the definition to something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `clean` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2017-07-07 16:00.00'
DO
BEGIN
   DECLARE isTime CHAR(1);
   SET isTime := IF(table_name.programed_time = NOW(), 'y', 'n');
   IF isTime = 'y' THEN 
      DELETE FROM `cell_name` WHERE `cell_name` = 'value';
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Basically, enclose the body in `BEGIN... END`

Comment: 2 errors were found during the analysis.
Type of date unknown. (Near "IF" at position 171)
Type of date unknown. (Near "END" at position 255) I thing has syntax errors.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I said "something like"... I've worked with events VERY little, but recall they declare similar to routines and triggers.

Comment: You also might try using a local variable, rather than session (@ prefixed) variable.

Comment: I can't declare a variable inside the event. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to do what I want, without having to create variables or store the date in the database.

Here is the code I use.

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `clean`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `clean`
       ON SCHEDULE
         EVERY 1 DAY
         STARTS '2017-01-27 16:00.00'
         COMMENT 'EVENT runs daily at 4 pm. DELETE executed first Monday month'
         DO
           BEGIN
             IF (DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 AND
                 DAYNAME(NOW()) = 'Monday') THEN
               DELETE FROM `table_name`
               WHERE `cell_name` = 'value';
             END IF;
           END//

DELIMITER ;
```